# Индекс по вложенному полю

Tags: mongodb

Добрый день. Есть коллекция документов следующего вида:

```
[
{User: { guid: 1, prop: 1}},
{User: { guid: 2, prop: 2}},
{Resource: {guid: 3, prop: 3}},
]
```

Есть задача индексировать User.guid как уникальный.
Но при создании второго ресурса я получу ошибку дублирования User.guid.

Вставить `{Resource: {guid: 4, prop: 3}}` не получится :-(

Выглядит индекс вот так:

```
...ensure_index({'User.guid': 1}, { unique: true});
```

В интернете я пока что ответа на вопрос не нашел :-(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Нужно было так:

```
ensure_index({'User.guid': 1}, { unique: true, sparse: true});
```